# При использовании прокси в cefsharp не грузятся страницы

Tags: c#, proxy, cefsharp

Загружаю браузер и прокси следующим образом

```
CefSettings cfsettings = new CefSettings();
cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "163.44.169.65:8181");
cfsettings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://2ip.ru");
```

После этого вместо любого сайта грузится белая blank страница. Нигде ответа нет, что делать? Без прокси все работает.

Comment: попробуйте `cfsettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", "socks5://163.44.169.65:8181");`

Comment: @Monomax не работает(. Причем не важно какой префикс делать, http//: , https//: и тд.